# How to remove the space char(32) at the end of Chinese character string?

Tags: sql-server

I cannot remove the space from the string '' in SQL Server 2016 under Windows 10 (Simplified Chinese edition).

```
select len(trim(N'胸痹心痛 ')), len(rtrim(N'胸痹心痛 ')), len(N'胸痹心痛 ')  

(No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)

4   4   4
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suspect you should be using `nvarchar`s here, not `varchar`s.

Comment: I tried both "varchar" and "nvarchar", neither approach works.

Comment: It does, like the below answer explains, you think `LEN` includes trailing spaces; it does ***not***.

Answer (score 3):

What I have understood from your question is, all the time length is 4, so maybe you are thinking it's not working.

But, According to [Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms190329(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) LEN()

> Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression,
> excluding trailing blanks.

also, they are suggesting using DATALENGTH()

> To return the number of bytes used to represent an expression, use the
> DATALENGTH function.

[Check Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/144099)

So your query is actually working fine.

Comment: Yes, datalength() returned different results.

select datalength(trim('胸痹心痛 ')), datalength(rtrim('胸痹心痛 ')), datalength('胸痹心痛 ')

8 8 9

But, still, any suggestion to remove the last space which is char(32)?

Comment: `RTRIM` and `TRIM`, the latter by default, remove all the trailing spaces, @GuangZheng , not just some of them. The fact you got 8, 8, 9 evidences this, as the latter value has a higher value (the one that isn't trimmed).

Comment: @GuangZheng I completely agree with Larnu, RTRIM/TRIM is doing the job for you.

But I am just curious to know, by any change do you want to remove space after every word? for example, 'The End Game' will become 'TheEndGame'?